# Octave load string from file to matrix

Tags: octave

I have a file having a single word(string) on each line. How can I read this file in octave in to a "matrix". So that a[1] = "word1".

Thanks a lot for reply.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be creating a Cell Array:

```
input_file = fopen('vocab.txt');
number_of_lines = fskipl(input_file, Inf);
frewind(input_file);
cells = cell(number_of_lines, 1);
for i = 1:number_of_lines
    cells{i} = fscanf(input_file, '%s', 1);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`textread (filepath, format)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFtextread) function:

```
column1 = textread('/path/to/file', '%s');    # Where '%s' indicates how to read the values of your file: one string per index.

for i = 1:rows(column1)
    word = column1{ i };

    %do your thing...
end
```

`column1` is a **cell array**. That is why we use `{}` for accessing it.

---

**Note**: If each line contained 2 words separated by a space, you would call:

`[column1, column2] = textread('/path/to/file', '%s %s');`

**Performance**: `textread()` is a wrapper based on `fscanf`. If you really need performance for file inputs then you may prefer to learn how to properly use [`fscanf(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Formatted-Input.html) and set the buffer length. See Terence's answer on how to use `fscanf()`.

 `textread()` reads my 100K entries of 4 columns (a 2Mb file) in ~30 seconds on my laptop. See the comments for further explanations.

Comment: This is a great answer, even better than the accepted one. I just wonder how performance compares between textread and fscanf.

Comment: Very Good remark! **implementation**
`fscanf` is a builtin function (written in C++) and `textread` is an octave function that calls fscanf in its implementation. fscanf is faster. (call `which 'textread'` in octave to see the file with its implementation) It does checks you would not do if you know your file well.  **Performance:** 
Try not to use `textread()` on large files. 5-10 Mb should be ok (my laptop once froze for 3 hours with a 100Mb file).
For a >=25 Mb file I would recommend splitting the file in smaller chunks.